# Two brands of chocolate are available in packs of $24$ and $15$ respectively.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Two brands of chocolate are available in packs of $24$ and $15$ respectively. If I need to buy an equal number of chocolates of both kinds, what is the least number of boxes of each kind I would need to buy?

I tried and found out the L.C.M. which is $120$. Now, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $24=3\cdot8$, $15=3\cdot5$, hence you must buy 5 packs of first kind and 8 of second kind.